# Superpowered: real time pitch shift with timestretcher not working

Tags: c++, superpowered

I am using Superpowered for various real-time FX and they all work very straightforward. However the pitch shifting is a whole other story, I think in fact because it's based on the time-stretching algorithm that of course has to deal with output that changes in time which is a lot more complex than applying FX like EQ or reverb. However I'm only interested in change the pitch of my mic input.

I looked at [the only example I could find on GitHub](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/issues/256) and I slightly adapted it to fit my work:

```
static bool audioProcessing(void *clientdata,
                            float **buffers,
                            unsigned int inputChannels,
                            unsigned int outputChannels,
                            unsigned int numberOfSamples,
                            unsigned int samplerate,
                            uint64_t hostTime) {
    __unsafe_unretained Superpowered *self = (__bridge Superpowered *)clientdata;

    SuperpoweredAudiobufferlistElement inputBuffer;

    inputBuffer.startSample = 0;
    inputBuffer.samplesUsed = 0;
    inputBuffer.endSample = self->timeStretcher->numberOfInputSamplesNeeded;
    inputBuffer.buffers[0] = SuperpoweredAudiobufferPool::getBuffer(self->timeStretcher->numberOfInputSamplesNeeded * 8 + 64);
    inputBuffer.buffers[1] = inputBuffer.buffers[2] = inputBuffer.buffers[3] = NULL;

    self->outputBuffers->clear();
    self->timeStretcher->process(&inputBuffer, self->outputBuffers);
    int samples = self->timeStretcher->numberOfInputSamplesNeeded;
    float *timeStretchedAudio = (float *)self->outputBuffers->nextSliceItem(&samples);
    if (timeStretchedAudio != 0) {
        SuperpoweredDeInterleave(timeStretchedAudio, buffers[0], buffers[1], numberOfSamples);
    }

    //self->outputBuffers->rewindSlice();

    return true;
}
```

I have removed most of the code that I thought wasn't necessary. For example there was a while loop that seemed to deal with time-stretch scenarios, I'm just outputting the same time as I input.

Some observations:

- If I don't `clear` the `outputBuffers` my memory usage goes through the roof
- If I use `self->outputBuffers->rewindSlice();` the app becomes silent, probably meaning the buffers are getting overwritten with silence
- If I do not use `self->outputBuffers->rewindSlice();` I can hear my own voice coming back, but `timeStretchedAudio` is always `0` except  the very first time

Comment: did you get the result? if so, do not tell me how?

Comment: No the feature took too much time and it is shelved for the moment. I think a complete example would have helped enormously to even understand how this was supposed to work.

Comment: @arsenium see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working:

```
static bool audioProcessing(void *clientdata,
                                float **buffers,
                                unsigned int inputChannels,
                                unsigned int outputChannels,
                                unsigned int numberOfSamples,
                                unsigned int samplerate,
                                uint64_t hostTime) {
    __unsafe_unretained Superpowered *self = (__bridge Superpowered *)clientdata;

    //timeStretching->setRateAndPitchShift(realTimeRate, realTimePitch);
    SuperpoweredAudiobufferlistElement inputBuffer;
    inputBuffer.startSample = 0;
    inputBuffer.samplesUsed = 0;
    inputBuffer.endSample = numberOfSamples;
    inputBuffer.buffers[0] = SuperpoweredAudiobufferPool::getBuffer((unsigned int) (numberOfSamples * 8 + 64));
    inputBuffer.buffers[1] = inputBuffer.buffers[2] = inputBuffer.buffers[3] = NULL;

    // Converting the 16-bit integer samples to 32-bit floating point.
    SuperpoweredInterleave(buffers[0], buffers[1], (float *)inputBuffer.buffers[0], numberOfSamples);
    //SuperpoweredShortIntToFloat(audioInputOutput, (float *)inputBuffer.buffers[0], (unsigned int) numberOfSamples);

    self->timeStretcher->process(&inputBuffer, self->outputBuffers);

    // Do we have some output?
    if (self->outputBuffers->makeSlice(0, self->outputBuffers->sampleLength)) {
        while (true) { // Iterate on every output slice.
            // Get pointer to the output samples.
            int numSamples = 0;
            float *timeStretchedAudio = (float *)self->outputBuffers->nextSliceItem(&numSamples);
            if (!timeStretchedAudio || *timeStretchedAudio == 0) {
                break;
            }

            // Convert the time stretched PCM samples from 32-bit floating point to 16-bit integer.
            //SuperpoweredFloatToShortInt(timeStretchedAudio, audioInputOutput,
            //                            (unsigned int) numSamples);
            SuperpoweredDeInterleave(timeStretchedAudio, buffers[0], buffers[1], numSamples);
            self->recorder->process(timeStretchedAudio, numSamples);

            // Write the audio to disk.
            //fwrite(audioInputOutput, 1, numSamples * 4, fd);
        }
        // Clear the output buffer list.
        self->outputBuffers->clear();
        // If we have enough samples in the fifo output buffer, pass them to the audio output.
        //SuperpoweredFloatToShortInt((float *)inputBuffer.buffers[0], audioInputOutput, (unsigned int) numberOfSamples);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am not sure if changing the rate also works, but I don't care for this application. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the part marked with TODO. That's the point where you need to provide input for the timeStretcher. Also take care of separating the output from the input. Output could be written before the input is consumed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think I already progressed a bit in the mean time and I've updated my question with the current code and some observations

Comment: You need to "consume" outputBuffers. Check the header on what options you have for this. Clear() removes everything.
Please note the buffer size. The time stretcher will return with 512 samples, but your audio I/O may work with a different buffer size. That's why the original code example is more complex.

Comment: @GaborSzanto Can you write in more detail what exactly should be in TODO? I don't quite understand = (

Comment: @GaborSzanto it just doesn't make sense to me and I'm looking at it for quite a while already. It's like a joke without the clue, we don't understand what the code is exactly about without seeing the final part. How does the timestretched audio end up in my output again without crackling?

Comment: @GaborSzanto and why does self->timeStretcher->numberOfInputSamplesNeeded stay at 0 after the first pass?